# If $A$ and B are two events such that $P(A) > 0$ and $P(A) + P(B) > 1$

Tags: probability

If A and B are two events such that $P(A) > 0$ and $P(A) + P(B) > 1$, then is

$P(B/A) \geq 1 - \frac{P(B')}{P(A)}  ?$

I could only get far
P(B/A) = $\frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(A)}$ = $\frac{P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)}{P(A)}$ > $\frac{1 - P(A \cup B)}{P(A)}$

Is this enough to say that the above statement isn't true?

Comment: Please consider demonstrating what you've tried to solve this problem.

Comment: I was still trying to fix my fraction. Anyway, edited the post with my own attempt as well. Also, why it has been negatively rated?

Comment: I may be missing something as I do not use $P(A)+P(B)\gt 1$.  Can you say   $$P(B \mid A)= \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \dfrac{P(A) - P(A \cap B')}{P(A)}= 1-\dfrac{P(A \cap B')}{P(A)} \ge 1-\dfrac{P(B')}{P(A)}$$

since $P(A \cap B') \le P(B')$ so  $-P(A \cap B') \ge -P(B')$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Your inequality (to be proved) is equivalent to, after a simplification:

$$P(A\cap B)\geq P(A)+P(B)-1$$

The RHS is greater than zero since $P(A)+P(B)>1$. Hence, we have to prove $P(A\cap B)>0$.

The last inequality is obviously true, since $P(A) + P(B) > 1$ is *not* possible for mutually exclusive events.

Comment: The book where I found this question has given the answer as false.

Comment: @navjotjsingh Well, I just proved it to be true ^_^ Let's wait for some more answers and see if I reached a wrong conclusion.

Comment: This isn't valid, unfortunately. You need to show that $P(A \cap B) \ge P(A) + P(B) - 1$; you've noted that $RHS > 0$. But you've then shown the *weaker* statement that $LHS > 0$. As a silly example to illustrate how this isn't sufficient, it's also true that $RHS > -100$, and trivially the $LHS \ge 0 > -100$. Similarly, doubling the RHS would maintain $RHS > 0$, but would make the original inequality 'harder' to prove